# Crack cryptographic hash functions using Toffoli gates?

Tags: hash

Might it be possible that reversible combinatorial circuits (or some emulating software) are going to be used to get the input of the white box?

I mean if I have constructed a proper reversible circuit then (in theory) I can obtain the input of whatever output I get. Am I missing the point?

Here is the relevant WP link for those interested: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a reversible circuit would have many additional output lanes. Since there are too many different values those can have(exponential in the number of extra lanes) you can't guess a complete output of such a circuit. Without a complete output of the circuit you can't reverse it. So your approach doesn't work.

If you could construct a reversible circuit with few additional output lanes, that'd break a hash-function. But there is no simple way construct such a circuit given a normal circuit.

> The Toffoli gate is universal; this means that for any boolean function f(x1, x2, ..., xm), there is a circuit consisting of Toffoli gates which takes x1, x2, ..., xm and some extra bits set to 0 or 1 and outputs x1, x2, ..., xm, f(x1, x2, ..., xm), **and some extra bits (called garbage)**. Essentially, this means that one can use Toffoli gates to build systems that will perform any desired boolean function computation in a reversible manner.

*Quoted from [Wikipedia: Toffoli gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate#Universality_and_Toffoli_gate)*

Comment: Follow up question: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14436/7760.